# ZMQ in Python - Can the PULL-side process know if the PUSH-side process was closed?

Tags: python, subprocess, zeromq, distributed-computing, pyzmq

I use `ZMQ` in python to distribute calculations between a master application and `worker` sub-processes, via a **`PUSH-PULL`**.

At times, the master might crash and the *sub-processes remain hanging*, listening to their respective ports.

I tried to use `atexit` to close the workers in the event that the master crashes, as suggested in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14128410/killing-child-process-when-parent-crashes-in-python). However `atexit` does not capture the case when I forcefully close the master.

Is there a way for the **`PULL`**-side worker sub-processes to notice that the **`PUSH`**-side master is closed via the `zmq sock` (as possibly hinted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25542110/kill-child-process-if-parent-is-killed-in-python/25634723#25634723))?

**Practical Solution (edit)**

A practical solution I implemented is to have the master `PUSH` a message to close all pending workers ***when it re-starts***:

Before spawning its own helpers, the new instance of the master broadcasts an `exit` message to all sockets.

Upon receiving the exit command, the hanging sub-processes (launched by the previous instance of the master) do a `sys.exit()`.

Answer (score 1):

### A: No, but workarounds exist

In case the sole **`PUSH-PULL`**:

**S**caleable **F**ormal **C**ommunication **P**attern remains on the scene, then the answer has no other option to be but: **no, cannot**.

---

### But ZeroMQ is a powerful mental shift into distributed processing concept

However, with some slight architecture shifts, the needed functionality comes in hand from other Formal Communication Patterns, deployed side-by-side with the initial **`PUSH-PULL`** solo.

[image]

The co-existent `TransportPLANE`(s) + `SIG_PLANE`(s) behavioural orchestration is limited only by one's imagination.

---

While not directly solving a code for your **[dead-man button] signalling scenario**, [**this** answer **illustrates the possible approaches in this direction** by focusing on co-existing BEHAVIOUR(s) rather than on code.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26688152/3666197)

- [Understanding advanced ZeroMQ socket types + **`The Book` -  a must read for `ZeroMQ`**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25742744/3666197)
- [Understanding the concept "under" ZeroMQ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30606563/3666197)

Comment: Sounds good & works like a devil -- Yes, both **ZeroMQ** & **nanomsg** are devilish good frameworks and I love to work with 'em. Enjoy 'em too.